# Wix Velo | Collection query returns no results

Tags: javascript, velo

I have a poll on my website that gathers some information from the users and saves it into a collection. Now I need to write some code to display how many users chose each option. I tried the following, but instead of the requested number the query returns `Promise<>`, with no value in the brackets.

The collection contains selection tags for each of the days of the week; there can be many choices for each day, hence I'm using `.contains()` method and not `.eq()`. But even if I remove the `.contains()` filter, the result is still the same - nothing - although it should return the number of all entries in the collection.

This is the function querying the collection:

```js
function countOccurences(field, option) {
    let number = wixData.query("LiveClassSchedulePoll")
    .contains(field, option)
    .count();

    console.log(number);
    return number;
}
```

And this is the dataset I am working with:
[image]

I would be grateful for any tips; I'm probably doing something very stupid and not understanding Velo API at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution! Here it is, in case someone encounters a similar issue.

A very simple thing, really. For some reason, if you finish your prompt with a `.count()` method, it returns this weird `Promise<>` object without a value. But it works just fine if you add a `.then()` method afterwards. Also, the function from which you call the method must be **async**, and you must call it using the **await** keyword.

Here is the now functioning method:

```
function countOccurences(field, option) {
    
    let number = wixData.query("LiveClassSchedulePoll")
    .contains(field, option)
    .count()
    .then(num => {
        return num;
    })
    
    return number;
}
```

This works perfectly fine, but to be honest, I still don't know why I need that `.then()` to access the result of the query. If any *velo* expert has a more detailed explanation I would love to hear it; I also don't understand why it didn't work without using asynchronous programming (the **await** keyword while calling the method).